# MX Record Failover When Primary ISP down

Tags: domain-name-system, email

I need some help to configure ISP Fail-over.

I have configured a Zimbra Mail Server on CentOS. It is working fine. We have 2 ISP connections and created 2 MX records for both ISP's like bellow

10.0.0.1 mail.example.com(mx) PTR record created in ISP1(Primary)
10.0.0.2 mail1.example.com(mx) PTR record created in ISP2(backup)

With this setup when my ISP1 is down we want to be able to access the Mail Server through ISP2. We are able to access mails internally.

But problem is users who are using mail services from outside organization have to change their mail client settings mail.example.com to mail1.example.com. They need to make the change to access their mail through through web access. They have to use mail1.example.com instead of mail.example.com

My requirement is we should not have to change any settings at user end, and when my ISP1 goes down it should automatically redirect to the MX record at ISP2

Can anybody suggest me how can I configure Fail-Over without changing any settings at mail client.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with MX records. MX records are used for incoming mail over SMTP. What you are looking for is DNS failover for your mail.example.com DNS record.

Most decent DNS providers can provide this service. They will monitor the record (mail.example.com) and if it detects the IP is not reachable, will automatically switch the record to your secondary IP.

Obviously, there is going to be some delay as the DNS provider will need to detect the outage and the clients will need to pick up the updated IP. but, generally, the process works fairly well and usually fairly quickly.

edit:

> 10.0.0.1 mail.example.com(mx) PTR record created in ISP1(Primary) 
>   10.0.0.2 mail1.example.com(mx) PTR record created in ISP2(backup)

MX records aren't PTR records either. Your MX records should point to the A records. The IP address used to send mail should have a corresponding PTR record.

Comment: Hi  Rex, Thanks for your response..  my domain is registered in networksolution.com, in public dns i have contacted them for this regards, but no use..

Comment: i have done settings for my test server in public dns, one mx record with 2 A records pointing to 2 different ISP's public IP's like bellow mx: mail.example.com     A Record: mail 10.0.0.1( A record point to ISP1 IP), A Record: mail 10.0.0.2( A record point to ISP2 IP).  will it works..?

Comment: Network Solutions is your registrar. While they may also be providing your DNS services, they may not offer DNS failover. You can move your DNS services to a more robust provider (DNSMadeEasy, Amazon Route 53 to name two that I could recommend). If you do not understand this - find/consult with someone that does.

Comment: What you just did was setup DNS round robin. Not the same as DNS failover as some clients may continue to try the other IP address.

Comment: Also note, that with DNS round robin setup, if both links are online, you will have users using both connections..Not sure if you wanted this crude form of load balancing or just straight failover.